# Retrieve data from Facebook real time stream

Tags: .net, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to create a Real Time processor for Facebook using the Real Time subscription API (https://graph.facebook.com/[AppID]/subscriptions).  I have everything working except I am completely stumped as to how to retrieve the information about the actual event from the data returned by the real time stream!  The data I get back is below, and there is no information on the ID of the object (Like, Status Update, Photo, etc.), the only information returned is the user ID in both the "id" field and the "uid" field.  Does anyone have any advice as to how to retrieve the information for the action?

```
{"object":"user","entry":[{"uid":"100002214799362","id":"100002214799362","time":1344618016,"changed_fields":["feed"]}]}
```